# Any way to set base url in the without reinstalling?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I built a site for a client on my subdomain. I then transferred it accross - files and data base - to a new server.

Problem is base url no longer works.

I manually set it, eg:

```
<base href="http://www.website.com/">
```

But this seems to make all links open in new tabs.

Is there any way I can fix this via the database or config file?

Comment: Did you try: `<base href="[[++site_url]]">` ?

Comment: @Vasis yes I did. The problem there is that it seems to have the old sub-domain URL saved in 'site_url' setting.

I cannot find that setting in the DB or config file though.

Comment: Did you try to clear `/core/cache/` folder manually?

Answer (score 1):

After moving a MODX site to another server, domain or subdomain, you need to check the following places and take actions:

- clear the site cache (!)
- check via FTP if cache folder is really empty
- if not -> set permissions, ask your hoster if 777 or 755
- edit templates to contain new base href
- check your .htaccess if you have old rewrite rules set
- check core/config for old paths or urls
- also check config.inc.php inside root folder, inside /manager/ and inside /connectors/.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the paths and urls in Modx are based off of the site-wide settings. There are probably several that you would have to adjust. core_path is the most basic of these.

These can be found under the gear in the top right corner of the manager, under 'system settings'

Also, if this and the config file are not enough alone, this SO question suggests re-installing the setup folder and re-running the initial setup.

[Move modx site from subfolder to root folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556466/move-modx-site-from-subfolder-to-root-folder)